# Eclipse plug-in: syntax recoloring

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a costum editor for my own languages and I want to change from the property menu between them and recolor the syntax accordingly. I don't know if I have to use a reconciler or something else. The only way that the syntax is recolored, is by closing and opening the current file.

Answer (score 0):

In your editor you need to listen for property change events from your preference store.

In your `initializeEditor` method call `setPreferenceStore(preferenceStore)`

Override the `handlePreferenceStoreChanged` method:

```java
@Override
protected void handlePreferenceStoreChanged(PropertyChangeEvent event)
{
  // TODO update settings affected by the event

  // TODO If required invalidate the current presentation to update the colors
  getSourceViewer().invalidateTextPresentation();

  super.handlePreferenceStoreChanged(event);
}
```

You need to add code to look at the property change event to see if it is one that you need to handle. If the event changes something (such as changing the colors) that needs to text to be redrawn call `getSourceViewer().invalidateTextPresentation()`.

To support all the normal text editor preferences you need to use a chained preference store in the `setPreferenceStore` call:

```java
IPreferenceStore generalTextStore = EditorsUI.getPreferenceStore();

IPreferenceStore yourPreferenceStore = get your preference store

IPreferenceStore combinedPreferenceStore = new ChainedPreferenceStore(new IPreferenceStore[] {yourPreferenceStore, generalTextStore});

setPreferenceStore(combinedPreferenceStore);
```